# What does "reveal" mean in this context?

Tags: legendary-bigtrouble

I just got the *[Legendary: Big Trouble in Little China](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/200171/legendary-big-trouble-little-china)* deck-building game. They recommend using this Mastermind, Six-Shooter, for your first play through, but I cant figure out what "reveal" means in this situation...

For the **Master Strike** text on this Mastermind card:

[image: six-shooter card]

Does that text mean I need to "reveal" one of those two types of Heroes from my **hand**, my **discard pile**, the **Hero Deck**, or somewhere else? I'm relatively new to the *Legendary* series, so maybe this is spelled out somewhere else, but not in the BTLC instructions. I just want to know I'm playing correctly.

I'd guess it meant to "reveal but not use" one of those Heroes from your **hand**, then discard it for later; this seems to make the only sense, as you'd be wasting a character for a few turns, or taking a Strike. Any other way, and it sounds like you're *adding* a Hero to your hand/deck, and that doesn't sound very much like a Master Strike effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Legendary: Marvel core rule book on page 17](http://www.upperdeck.com/OP/RuleBooks/Legendary_Rules-Core_Set.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> “Reveal a card” just means show the other players that you have it. You don’t play or discard the card you revealed. When you have the opportunity to “reveal a card”, **you can reveal a card from your hand or you can reveal a card in front of you that you have already played this turn.**

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be explicitly stated in the rules for *Big Trouble in Little China*, but they same rules likely apply.

---

In the context of this card, you will (almost always) end up revealing a card from your hand. The reveal happens as part of the Master Strike for Six Shooter, which most likely happens at the beginning of a player's turn when the top card of the villain deck is revealed. In some other Legendary versions it's possible to reveal the top card of the villain deck in the middle of a player's turn, but I haven't played this enough to know whether that's possible in the *Big Trouble in Little China* version.